# Reading GIT Merge Markers

Tags: git, merge

Sorry, this is a very simple question. What does this merge marker mean in GIT

```
>>>>>>> next-release:db/schema.rb
```

when it's got no accompanying?

```
=======
```

Also, is there some way to tell GIT to just choose one version over another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To tell `Git` to choose one version over another (of an unmerged path), you can use one of :

- `git checkout --ours -- path/to/file`
- `git checkout --theirs -- path/to/file`

See the [`git checkout` man page](http://www.all.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) for details.

Regarding the merge marker; I have never seen a ">>>>" added without a matching "====" and "<<<<".  Are you sure this wasn't left over from an attempt to manually resolve the conflict?

The tag `next-release:db/schema.rb` simply indicates that the file "db/schema.rb" is on the "next-release" branch.

Comment: Cool, +1 and thanks for that, Tim. It could indeed be that it was left over from an earlier conflict, since I had this problem last time I merged, and I don't know how I resolved it :)

Comment: The `--ours` and `--theirs` are excellent tips. I obsessively read man pages to find options and still forget about those sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this thread, be careful if you got a merge conflict during a **rebase**.

> its confusing when resolving a merge conflict.
>   In the past I could use:

```
git checkout --theirs -- <filename>
```

> to checkout theirs version but now I have to do:

```
git checkout --ours -- <filename>
```

> to checkout theirs version.

Check "[Why is the meaning of “ours” and “theirs” reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2960751/6309)" to see why the options are reversed when rebasing.

And as mentioned in "[How can I discard remote changes and mark a file as “resolved”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073841/how-can-i-discard-remote-changes-and-mark-a-file-as-resolved)", don't forget to use the '--' between the checkout options and the filename.

> If you don't do this, and the filename happens to match the name of a branch or tag, Git will think that you want to check that revision out, instead of checking that filename out, and so use the first form of the checkout command.