# git: ignore a file on pull from remote1, but push local version to remote2

Tags: git, gitignore, git-pull, git-remote, git-checkout

I have 3 git repositories:

- `local`: my development repo on my local machine;
- `remote1` used for collaboration with other developers;
- `remote2` which is a Production server.

  1. I would like to `pull` regularly from `remote1` to my `local` repo and keep some local tracked files intact (i.e. fetch and merge from `remote1`, but exclude some local tracked files from being merged).
  2. On the other side, I would like to regularly `push` to `remote2` and I would like local tracked files to be pushed as well.

In other words, I would like to have the following versions of `file1`:

- `local`: file1 *v.1*
- `remote1`: file1, *v.2*
- `remote2`: file1, *v.1*

Note: `file1` can be anything (.css, .html, even .png)

I have tried the following approaches:

- `.gitignore` a file (does not work, the file becomes being tracked again after pull from `remote1`)
- `git pull --no-ff --no-commit remote1 master`, then `git checkout --ours file1` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073841/how-can-i-discard-remote-changes-and-mark-a-file-as-resolved) (does not work, file1 becomes v.2)
- `.git/info/exclude` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753070/git-ignore-files-only-locally/1753078#1753078) (does not work, nothing is ignored and even if it is ignored, `file1` will not be pushed to `remote2` then)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to a:

- `git update-index --assume-unchanged -- path/to/file1` *before* pulling from `remote1`, and
- `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged -- path/to/file1` just after pulling from `remote1`.

(If that doesn't work, try also `git update-index --skip-worktree`)

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What does this command do underneath? Is it possible to push in the same manner?

Comment: @MartinLee http://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/6309. You can remove that option before pushing.