# Why is the meaning of “ours” and “theirs” reversed with git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I use git-svn and I noticed that when I have to fix a merge conflict after performing a `git svn rebase`, the meaning of the `--ours` and `--theirs` options to e.g. `git checkout` is reversed. That is, if there's a conflict and I want to keep the version that came from the SVN server and throw away the changes I made locally, I have to use `ours`, when I would expect it to be `theirs`.

Why is that?

Example:

```
mkdir test
cd test
svnadmin create svnrepo
svn co file://$PWD/svnrepo svnwc
cd svnwc
echo foo > test.txt
svn add test.txt
svn ci -m 'svn commit 1'
cd ..
git svn clone file://$PWD/svnrepo gitwc
cd svnwc
echo bar > test.txt 
svn ci -m 'svn commit 2'
cd ..
cd gitwc
echo baz > test.txt 
git commit -a -m 'git commit 1'
git svn rebase

git checkout --ours test.txt
cat test.txt 
# shows "bar" but I expect "baz"

git checkout --theirs test.txt
cat test.txt 
# shows "baz" but I expect "bar"
```

Comment: Jut updated my answer with lots of diagrams to better illustrate the "ours" and "theirs" sides.

Comment: See also https://github.com/git/git/commit/f30301657b68561392d910f6196380dd3976549e

Answer (score 249, accepted):

That seems consistent with what a rebase does.

- [`git svn rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) will fetch revisions from the SVN parent of the current HEAD and rebases the current (uncommitted to SVN) work against it.
- [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) does mention:
  Note that a rebase merge works by replaying each commit from the working branch on top of the `<upstream>` branch.
  Because of this, when a merge conflict happens:

  - **the side reported as ours is the so-far rebased series, starting with `<upstream>`**,
  - **and theirs is the working branch**.
    In other words, **the sides are swapped**.

> git rebase replays each commit from the working branch on top of the `<upstream>` branch.

If you reconcile both definitions:

- the commits coming from SVN are the ones on top of which local Git commits are replayed. They are part of the "so-far rebased series", and are referenced as "our" (in your case, the `test.txt` file with `bar` content)
- the working branch (containing Git commits unknown to SVN, in your case, the `test.txt` file with `baz` content) is "their", and each of those local Git commits are being replayed.

In other words, SVN or not:

- the "`<upstream>`" branch (on top of which anything is replayed, and which is part of the so far "rebased commits") is "**ours**".
- what is being replayed (the working branch) is "**theirs**".

---

Good [mnemonic tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576415/what-is-the-precise-meaning-of-ours-and-theirs-in-git-especially-in-referen/25576672#comment39946814_25576672) by [CommaToast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811519/commatoast):

> **whatever HEAD's pointing to is "ours"**

(and the first thing a `git rebase upstream` does is to check out the `upstream` branch on top of which you want to rebase: HEAD refers to `upstream` -- `ours` now.)

This does *not* contradict:

- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50201532/6309), where a `git checkout --ours codefile.js` selects a file from `master` during a `git rebase master`
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60195781/6309), where `master`, the upstream branch you are rebasing onto, is referenced as "ours"

---

The confusion is likely coming from the role of the working branch in a classic [`git merge`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html).
When you are merging:

- the "working branch" is the one containing what is "so far merged", and is considered as "our",
- while the other commit represent what is being -- not replayed but -- merge on top of the working branch, and considered as "their".

As the `git rebase` man page mentions, a merge during a rebase means the side are swapped.

---

Another way to say the same thing is to consider that:

- **what we have** on the checked out branch is '**ours**',
- **what we had** (and is being merged or replayed) is '**theirs**'.

---

**On a merge**:

```
x--x--x--x--x(*) <- current branch B ('*'=HEAD)
    \
     \
      \--y--y--y <- other branch to merge
```

, we don't change the current branch 'B', so what we have is still what we were working on (and we merge from another branch)

```
x--x--x--x--x---------o(*)  MERGE, still on branch B
    \       ^        /
     \     ours     /
      \            /
       --y--y--y--/  
               ^
              their
```

---

But **on a rebase**, we switch side (as in [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch), mentioned in [`git rebase` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)) because the first thing a rebase does is to check out the upstream branch! (to replay the current commits on top of it)

```
x--x--x--x--x(*) <- current branch B
    \
     \
      \--y--y--y <- upstream branch
```

A **`git rebase upstream`** will first change `HEAD` of B to the upstream branch `HEAD` (hence the switch of 'ours' and 'theirs' compared to the previous "current" working branch.)

```
x--x--x--x--x <- former "current" branch, new "theirs"
    \
     \
      \--y--y--y(*) <- upstream branch with B reset on it,  
                       new "ours", to replay x's on it
```

, and then the rebase will replay 'their' commits on the new 'our' B branch:

```
x--x..x..x..x <- old "theirs" commits, now "ghosts", available through reflogs
    \
     \
      \--y--y--y--x'--x'--x'(*) <-  branch B with HEAD updated ("ours")
               ^
               |
        upstream branch
```

---

The only extra step with **`git svn rebase`** is that a svn "fetch" is performed first on the Git remote branch representing SVN commits.
You have initially:

```
x--x--x--x--x(*) <- current branch B, "ours" for now.
    \                                   
     \
      \--y--y--y <- SVN tracking branch, "theirs for now"
```

, you first update the SVN tracking branch with new commits coming from SVN

```
x--x--x--x--x(*) <- current branch B, still "ours", not for long
    \                                   
     \
      \--y--y--y--y'--y' <- SVN tracking branch updated
```

, then you switch the current branch to the SVN side (which becomes "ours")

```
x--x--x--x--x <- for "B", now "their" during the rebase
    \                                   
     \
      \--y--y--y--y'--y'(*) <- SVN tracking branch updated, and branch B: 
                               now "ours" (this is "what we now have")
```

, before replaying the commits you were working on (but which are now "theirs" during that rebase)

```
x--x..x..x..x <- old "theirs" commits, now "ghosts", available through reflogs
    \
     \
      \--y--y--y--y'--y'--x'--x'--x'(*) <-  branch B with HEAD updated ("ours")
                      ^
                      |
        upstream SVN tracking branch
```

Comment: @epologee: you are welcome. It is also useful when you are using only git, to understand what is going on during a rebase vs. a merge. And it adds to the upstream definition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166

Comment: My GOD!!! What kind of drugs was Torvalds taking?  This is way too complicated! Git is a very dangerous tool. You can easily destroy all of your work if you try to use outside knowledge or your intuition. Sofware development has gone down the worm hole!

Comment: @user148298 There is nothing wrong for this function. You don't have to know all those sort of things unless you are a git expert. And if you do require advanced functions you will have to learn it first.

Comment: I'm still confused. The statement [_Whatever HEAD's pointing to is "ours"_] seems to conflict with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50201532/10027592) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60195781/10027592) answers. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @starriet I have edited the answer to mention this is *not* in conflict with the two answers you are mentioning, where a `git rebase master` means "`ours`" is now `master`. To do a rebase, HEAD needs to first reference `master`, the upstream branch you are rebasing onto, which means `master` becomes "ours".

Comment: @VonC Thank you! In your answer _"But on a rebase, we switch side because..."_, does the word 'switch' mean changing the location of HEAD, i.e. `git switch`? Is it what this sentence in [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) is talking about?: _"If `<branch>` is specified, `git rebase` will perform an automatic `git switch <branch>` before doing anything else."_

Comment: @starriet Yes, as in `git switch` (that [I prensented here in 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)). But do understand that, when I used the "switch" term in my answer in 2010, the 2019 `git switch` command did not exist yet! ;) The general idea remains the same, though. HEAD moves at the beginning of a rebase, and what is "ours" moves with it.