# Git fetch/rebase master branch when other branch is checked out

Tags: git, branch, git-pull, git-checkout

Currently when I'm working on my local feature branch in order to get latest changes I need to do the following:

```
git checkout master
git fetch
git rebase
git checkout my-feature
git rebase master
```

Is there a simplier solution to just pull changes to master branch without switching to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Git will always switch to `master` behind the scene, to perform the rebase (considering that `rebase` starts by a checkout of the destination branch:
see "[`git rebase`, keeping track of '`local`' and '`remote`'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051461/git-rebase-keeping-track-of-local-and-remote/3052118#3052118)").

You just can use the shortcut [`git pull --rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull):

```
git pull --rebase master:master
git checkout my-feature
git rebase master
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do a`git fetch` followed by a `git rebase origin/master` That should rebase your topic-branch against master. Don't know if the fetch is really necessary though.

Comment: The fetch is required as you probably want to get the modifications from origin. Rebase origin/master is a "shortcut": your feature branch will then be both : rebased with regards to origin/master and ahead of your local master. Your local master will _not_ be updated to the state of origin/master which was the original question

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed the question below the code. I thought Sly only wanted to update his topic-branch without touching his own master.