# how to abort merge of a specific file using git?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, merge

I'm using git.

I have done `pull` action. and there was a merge conflict.

I want to return a **specific file** to version before the merge.

How do i do this?

After I have done this I want to pull this file only.

There will be a merge conflict. How do I:

a) take the remote version as conflict resolution?

b) take the local version as the conflict resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the version you want:

```
git checkout --ours -- afile
git checkout --theirs -- afile
```

See the gitready article "[keep either file in merge conflicts](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/25/keep-either-file-in-merge-conflicts.html) ".

Make sure to read "[Why is the meaning of “ours” and “theirs” reversed with `git rebase`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3052118/6309)", because if your merge conflict occurs during a git rebase...
then keeping your local version would be `git checkout --theirs -- afile`(!).

Comment: I want to return a specific file to version before the merge.

How do i do this?

Comment: @EladBenda `git checkout --ours -- afile` (if this is during a `git merge` or `git pull`, meaning you are still in the conflict resolution step: your `git pull` isn't finished yet: you are still resolving conflict, but, for that file, you want to preserve the local version)