# Meaning of local or remote in git gui

Tags: git-gui

I am somewhat confused what local / remote version means for git gui. At times remotes are my changes and at others local are. Is there any logic behind this naming/handling?

Comment: Are you asking what local & remote in git is, in general?

Comment: I know what local branches, etc. are in contrast to remote ones. That said - local and remote without any context - I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depends where, on [git-gui](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) you see "local" and "remote".

The only aspect of git where those two terms reference different changes is on a diff view, where local and remote are reversed during a rebase.

See "[git rebase, keeping track of 'local' and 'remote'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3052118/6309)"

> A rebase switches `ours` (current branch before rebase starts) and `theirs` (the upstream branch on top you want to rebase).
>   In a GUI mergetool context:
>
> - **`local`** references the partially rebased commits: "`ours`" (the upstream branch)
> - **`remote`** refers to the incoming changes: "`theirs`" - the current branch before the rebase.