# Git: How do I commit(?) an updated file after updating my branch from master?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git and have updated my branch from master by:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout my-feature
git merge master
```

I had a merge conflict and fixed the file manually.

My question is what now? How do I commit my fixes (if that is the correct term here) and ensure my branch is up-to-date so that I can push to Github and continue working? My branch is in its merging state (`my-branch|MERGING`), can I `git add` and commit in this state?

Comment: If you run `git status`, it should tell you what's up and what commands you can run.

Comment: @melpomene yes it shows a list of files that have been modified or are new (these are files I have not worked on but would have been updated in Master by other people) under 'Changes to be committed'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: I'm talking about the output under #3 in https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/#competing-line-change-merge-conflicts: "*(use "git add ..." to mark resolution)*" and then "*(fix conflicts and run "git commit")*".

Answer (score 0):

If:

- `git status` does not show `use "git add ..." to mark resolution`
- `git diff` does not show any merge marker left (as [I illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28936716/6309))

Then you can commit what is currently staged, and push. And keep working on your current modification.