# How to fix "You are in the middle of an am session" in a git branch?

Tags: git

## Issue

*Setup*

git version 2.17.1

*Problem*

I have an issue in a branch **origin/dev_xxx** of a git repository. I don't remenber how I got the following status (I didn't used git am) :

```
$ git status
On branch dev_xxx
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev_xxx'.

You are in the middle of an am session.
The current patch is empty.
  (use "git am --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git am --abort" to restore the original branch)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

```
$ git am --abort
fatal: could not parse author script
```

**I would like to come back to the original state of the branch.**

I read the following discussion but it doesn't answer to my issue (*The current patch is empty*)
[[What does "You are in the middle of an am session" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875767/what-does-you-are-in-the-middle-of-an-am-session-mean])

## Tests

To fix the issue I tried the following solutions with no success :

```
git am --skip or --abort
fatal: could not parse author script
```

```
git reset --hard dev_xxx
```

Each time I have still the status : *You are in the middle of an am session...*

Comment: That particular `fatal: could not parse ...` is a Git bug. I'm not sure if it's fixed in a more current Git, though. (The `abort` should finish even if there's something else wrong.)

Comment: Update: some tests for similar failures were introduced in Git 2.19, and Git 2.19 definitely fixes related bugs. It may also fix this one. Try updating to 2.19 or newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never been stuck in such a place but you may be able to get out by deleting a folder called rebase-apply or am-apply or something like this under your .git folder.

If you are not used to git, you can post the result of:
`ls -al .git`

We will see what seems to be relevant...

Comment: Ok, I deleted the folder "rebase-apply", it works fine, it fixed my issue. Thanks a lot.