# How to correctly perform a git mergetool

Tags: git, pandas, github, merge, git-merge

I'm trying to push a bug fix to the `pandas` github repository. Before pushing I had to perform the following commands to make sure my master branch is updated:

```
# go to the master branch
git checkout master
# pull changes from github
git fetch upstream
# update the master branch
git rebase upstream/master
# push it to your Github repo
git push
```

Then, I update the local branch:

```
# go to the feature branch
git checkout my-new-feature
# make a backup in case you mess up
git branch tmp my-new-feature
# rebase on master
git rebase master
```

`git rebase master` failed because there are conflicts to solve. To solve them, I'm using `git mergetool`, which I've associated with Meld, an open source tool to display LOCAL (left), BASE (middle) and REMOTE (right) files.

[image: Code present in the LOCAL file but not the REMOTE]

In this case I have some code in the LOCAL file which is not present in the remote. I didn't add that code, so I'm assuming the code has been removed by a merge upstream, while I was working on my local branch. I would therefore opt for removing the code from my LOCAL, in order to have LOCAL, BASE and REMOTE aligned.

[image: REMOTE and BASE diverge]

Now, what about the picture above? Last time I tried to take the changes from the REMOTE file, but when I've pushed my change on GitHub, it looked like I the added white-spaces were not from the remote, but I added them. Am I misunderstanding what REMOTE, LOCAL and BASE means?

To me REMOTE is the upstream version, LOCAL the local file I'm working on and BASE a partial merge git was able to carry over, but requires some manual intervention to complete.

How do you perform manual merges? I would take everything from the REMOTE but the changes I personally made.

What makes me doubt about my initial understanding of what LOCAL and REMOTE are, is the following picture.

[image]

I wrote the code highlighted in the right hand side

```
- ``concat`` will now use existing Series names if provided (:issue:`10698`).

  .. ipython:: python

     foo = pd.Series([1,2], name='foo')
     bar = pd.Series([1,2])
     baz = pd.Series([4,5])

  Previous Behavior:

  .. code-block:: python

     In [1] pd.concat([foo, bar, baz], 1)
     Out[1]:
           0  1  2
        0  1  1  4
        1  2  2  5

  New Behavior:

  .. ipython:: python

    pd.concat([foo, bar, baz], 1)
```

So why is that in the REMOTE and not in the LOCAL? I would expect it to be in the LOCAL file and not in the REMOTE, considering that hasn't been merged yet upstream.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in "[git rebase, keeping track of 'local' and 'remote'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3052118/6309)"

```
git checkout A
git rebase   B    # rebase A on top of B
```

You have:

- local is `B`,
- remote is `A`

(ours and theirs are reversed during a rebase)

So, in a GUI mergetool context:

- **local** references the partially rebased commits: "ours" (the upstream branch)
- **remote** refers to the incoming changes: "theirs" - the current branch before the rebase.