# git rebase upside down

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I'm trying to rebase my local feature branch on remote branch called 'integration'.

So I did-

```
git checkout feature
git rebase integration
```

but in my conflict resolution editor, I see changes from feature at the bottom and 'integration' on top, which I believe is upside down. How do I fix it?

It looks like-

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
<code from integration>
=======
<code from feature>
>>>>>>>
```

Comment: This has always confused me because it's the opposite order when fixing a conflict during a merge

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, just resolve the conflict and continue. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a `rebase`, branches are switched, and that's why they appeared to be inverted in your conflict resolution editor.

According to [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> Note that a rebase merge works by replaying each commit from the working branch on top of the <upstream> branch.

So the your local branch `feature` commits are applied to the upstream branch `integration`.

This causes a lot of confusion and there's nothing to do about it, just remember branches will be inverted when rebasing.

When resolving conflicts, your local branch is referred as `ours` while the other branch is referred as `theirs`. During a rebase conflict resolution, `ours` appears are theirs and `theirs` appears as ours. So if you want to know more about this issue you can search for other answers on SO using keywords "ours", "theirs" and "rebase". One great answer [is this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051461/git-rebase-keeping-track-of-local-and-remote) that I used to answer yours and it goes further in the explanation, if I wasn't clear enough.