# Git: Rebase Terminology

Tags: git

Given the following branches

```
     A---B---C topic (HEAD)
    /
D---E---F---G master
```

and running the command

```
git rebase master
```

Does that mean, that we are

- rebasing `topic/HEAD` on `master`, or...
- rebasing `master` with `topic/HEAD`?

I can't infer how I would express this action in a sentence from the `git-rebase` man pages.

PS: I know what `rebase` is and what it does, I just want to know "how to speak" the command, since the first argument is actually called `upstream`.

Comment: It's the former ("rebasing topic on master"). When you give `git rebase` a single argument, that one argument—`master`, in this case—serves two purposes: it tells which commits *not* to copy, and it tells *where the copies go*. Your current branch supplies the commits to be copied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first, rebasing topic/HEAD on master.

You're taking all the commits up to and including the latest of master. The current state/the latest commit of master is now again the 'base' on which you based your work.

You rebased that work on (the work already done in) master.

And (copies of) your commits will be added at the end, after the last commit in master. Credits to Makoto for supplying the graphic that explains the above.

For more reference materials, I personally think [this tutorial by Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) explains it really nicely, including similar graphics. 
The basic rebasing is a 2 minute read, after which it continues with interactive rebasing, which is a really, really nice feature to have in your toolkit!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Seemed to make more sense to me anyway.

Comment: I know how to rebase and what it does, I just wasn't sure how to put the command in a correct sentence (since the first argument is technically called `upstream`).

Comment: No doubt, Erik. I just emphasized it in that wording so hopefully you won't have to doubt again which was rebased on which. :)

Answer (score 5):

The resultant branch layout would be as follows:

```
      A---B---C ("dangling", waiting for garbage collection)
     /
D---E---F---G---A'---B'---C' < topic (HEAD)
            ^
          master
```

You would be **rebasing** your `topic` (current) branch with **`master`**, thus changing the ancestry of A (now A' since it's not *quite* the same commit) from E to G.

Comment: I didn't want to edit it myself, but for clarity I would have added on your graph the commits A, B and C (still existing with A pointing to E), with the comment "dangling", to make the copy aspect of the operation even clearer. I have upvoted anyway, this is a useful answer.

Comment: @RomainValeri:  That would be true had there been a remote branch, but there's no indication that there is.

Comment: ...a remote branch? A rebase is entirely local, what do you mean? OK, I have edited just to show you what I meant, feel free to rollback of course.

Comment: I think this is fine.  No real complaints here.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to know "how to speak" the command, since the first argument is actually called upstream.

I always mentally read that `git rebase master` command as:

> rebase the current branch ***on top of*** master (the upstream branch)

That is: replay all commit from `master` (excluded) up to the current branch HEAD on top of master.

Check out also "[git rebase, keeping track of 'local' and 'remote'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3052118/6309)"