# How to synchronize two git-svn repos

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

i have to use a subversion repository and i'd like to use git-svn. I switch the computer sometimes and at the moment i need to commit my changes and update the other computer. Sometimes the changed code wouldn't work, so my idea would be to create two git-svn repos and synchronize them with push/pull, and sometimes sync them (or one of them) with the svn repository. Would that be possible?
Switching the repository to git is no option. (Sadly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to sync with SVN your Git repo from both of your computer, then yes: each repo will be a "git-svn" one.
You create 2 repos, and then create your own set of git branches on top of the git-svn ones.

But you must not merge/push/pull any branch that will be dcommit'ed back to SVN: You need to pay attention to the [CAVEATS section of git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_caveats):

> For the sake of simplicity and interoperating with Subversion, it is recommended that all `git svn` users `clone`, `fetch` and `dcommit` directly from the SVN server, and avoid all git `clone`/`pull`/`merge`/`push` operations between git repositories and branches. The recommended method of exchanging code between git branches and users is git format-patch and git am, or just 'dcommit’ing to the SVN repository.
>
> Running `git merge` or `git pull` is NOT recommended on a branch you plan to `dcommit` from because Subversion users cannot see any merges you’ve made. Furthermore, if you `merge` or `pull` from a git branch that is a mirror of an SVN branch, `dcommit` may commit to the wrong branch.

Comment: So it says i should only exchange code between the git-svn repos via the svn repo?

Comment: uhm, the other way would then be to have only one git-svn repo with at least one non-svn branch wich could be pushed/pulled from the other machine. But in this way i could only dcommit from the one git-svn, right?

Comment: @John: you could still `dcommit` from both `git svn` branches provided you carefully update those same branch first.

Comment: meaning i have to do a git-svn rebase first?

Comment: @John: exactly (that reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959443/why-is-the-meaning-of-ours-and-theirs-reversed-with-git-svn/2960751#2960751).

Answer (score 2):

I would say `rsync` the two repos across the two machines. You would have the same repo.

Comment: So i'd basically have one repo which is rsynced between the machines, right? Would two different os be a problem? (XP <--> Linux)

Comment: @John Smith - No that should not be a problem, just make sure the CRLF settings are fine.