# How do you rebase the current branch's changes on top of changes being merged in?

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-rebase

Okay. If I'm on a branch (say `working`), and I want to merge in the changes from another branch (say `master`), then I run the command `git-merge master` while on the `working` branch, and the changes get merged in without rebasing the history at all. If I run `git-rebase master`, then the changes in `master` are rebased to be put on the top of my `working` branch. But what if I want to merge in the changes from `master` but rebase my changes in `working` to be on top? How do I do that? Can it be done?

I could run `git-rebase working` on my `master` branch to put my changes on top in the `master` branch, but I'd like to be able to do that in my `working` branch, and I have no idea how. The closest that I can think of doing is creating a new branch from `master` and then rebase `working`'s changes on top of that, but then I'd have a new branch instead of altering the `working` branch.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

You've got what `rebase` does backwards. `git rebase master` does what you're asking for — takes the changes on the current branch (since its divergence from master) and replays them on top of `master`, then sets the head of the current branch to be the head of that new history. It *doesn't* replay the changes from `master` on top of the current branch.

Comment: @Jonathan it's cool. This is a little bit of a tricky topic. By the way, `git rebase working` would move `master`'s changes (after the point that `working` branched off) to be on top of the `working` branch — but that's not a very sensible thing to do to `master` :)

Answer (score 90):

Another way to look at it is to consider `git rebase master` as:

> Rebase the current branch **on top of** `master`

Here , '`master`' is the **upstream** branch, and that explain why, during a rebase, [`ours` and `theirs` are reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959443/why-is-the-meaning-of-ours-and-theirs-reversed-with-git-svn/2960751#2960751).

Comment: That also explains why LOCAL and REMOTE are reversed. Thanks.

Comment: @AVIDeveloper on LOCAL and REMOTE, you can also read http://stackoverflow.com/a/3052118/6309

Comment: @@VonC: Thanks. Yep, after spending an afternoon mumbling to myself "REMOTE is my branch.. LOCAL is not mine", it all sunk in. Honestly, I would've preferred seeing the branch names (or abbrev. SHA) instead of REMOTE/LOCAL/ours/theirs/mine. My thoughts are the same regarding the `git difftool`'s horrible left/right. Kinda off topic, but for `difftool` I stick to git-meld and enjoy names like 'working-dir', 'stash@{0}', as so on.

Comment: @VonC: Can you explain how can it be that after we do:  `git checkout branch_to_update git rebase master` I get in git log the commits of master on top of local branch, instead the opposite?

Comment: @JavaSa That is strange, unless the rebase was not properly completed? You might need to ask a separate question with more details in it.

Comment: The problem arise regarding conflicts(file in which have different line conflicting, or code that has been modified in both branch), so resolve them is the most tricky part, as you will need to decide what keep for each file, this is especially true for large changes

Comment: @CarmineTambascia I agree. [git rerere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70922739/6309), but ultimately, it is a project management/communication issue, which will help minimize concurrent development on a common file.

Answer (score 5):

when rebasing current changes on top of master, you can:

1. pull down latest master: `git pull <remote_name> master`
2. checkout the branch you want to rebase changes into: `git checkout <branch_name>`
3. perform rebase: `git rebase master`

an alternative path that lets you rebase changes from a remote branch (origin/master, for example)into a local branch without updating the remote branch locally is: `git rebase origin/master`

Answer (score 1):

If a [maintainer](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/pull/21409#issuecomment-1707246215) asks you to **rebase** and **re-push** your [PR](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/pull/21409) you may follow this procedure on the CLI:

```bash
git switch blead # making sure I'm in "main"
git pull # update local with remote
git switch blead-3 # branch of this PR

git rebase blead # put this commit on top
git push --force # re-push after rebasing
```

---

Tried on Windows where GitHub asked for authorization via the web browser.