# Conflict when using git rebase

Tags: git

This is what I've done in my local git repository:

```
git checkout -b temp
// made some changes
git commit -am "Fix button color"
// made some changes
git commit -am "Fix button shadow"
git revert bda326fd1
git merge master
// fix conflicts
// made some changes
git commit -am "Fix button size"
```

Now, `git log --oneline` gives me this:

```
0da44b017 (HEAD -> temp) Fix button size
b54f819ed Merge branch 'master' into temp
66a6de811 Revert "Fix button shadow"
bda326fd1 Fix button shadow
d467f28f4 Fix button color
```

Now, before pushing changes to remote, I would like to completelly remove theese commits:

```
66a6de811 Revert "Fix button shadow"
bda326fd1 Fix button shadow
```

I wanted to use `git rebase` to `drop` theese 2 commits, but after doing: `git rebase -i HEAD~5` I got an error:

```
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

It want me to fix conflict, that was already fixed in past. Why does that happen? It was fixed waaay before my work I've talked above.

Comment: This is normal in Git: unless you tell it to do so, it will not remember and re-use previous resolutions. (There's debate on making the default "do remember and re-use" instead of "don't remember and re-use", so in general a lot of people think it's safe to turn this feature on. Just be sure you understand exactly how it works first!)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, try and:

> then resolve conflicts although the code looked the same.

- activate [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere), with [`git config rerere.enabled`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-rerereenabled).
- train it, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4155237/6309), with [`rerere-train.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89bece5c8c96f0b962cfc89e63f82d603fd60bed/contrib/rerere-train.sh) in order to benefit from past resolution.

Then try again your interactive rebase, to see if a trained and activate rerere would help.

Comment: I activaated `git rerere` and trained branch with script, but its not working. Still, conflicts arent not getting solved.

Comment: @dafie You might need to bite the bullet and, with rerere active, resolve those conflicts. Once that is done, such a resolution should not present itself again, considering you recorded those merge conflicts.