# Git makes me redo a big merge the next time I try to merge something

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

There are 2 branches of an opensource project on github:
**cat** and **cheetah**

**Cheetah** has a lot of differences vs **cat**, but all the **cat** changes are merged into **cheetah**, however not the other way around.

If I do a big commit[s] on **cat** in my **local-cat** branch, and wait for them to be merged first; and then I then make a merge commit for **cat => local-cheetah => cheetah**; it works fine.

But it could be days before the admin merges my **local-cat** code, so I need to be able to make my changes in **local-cat**, and the branch **cheetah** into **local-cheetah**, and make the merge commit from **local-cat => local-cheetah**, publish both PRs, and have it work.

So 2 PRs, one from **local-cat => cat**

And one with **local-cat => local-cheetah => cheetah**

(Worth noting the maintainer does a **squash** for all commits to **cat**, but did a **merge** commit for the **local-cheetah => cheetah** PR.)

***The problem when doing this is*** when I do it as just described, their last common ancestor is still the commit before I did anything, so the next time we have to do a merge from **cat => cheetah**, even if it's tiny, someone has to redo all the merge conflicts from my big merge.

How can I prevent this from happening without waiting for my **local-cat** PR to commit to **cat** and then merging **cat => local-cheetah**?

Comment: Do a real merge instead of a fake-merge with a squash commit.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem when doing this is when I do it as just described, their last common ancestor is still the commit before I did anything

That is what rebase exists:

- rebase `local-cheetah` on top of `origin/local-cheetah`
- then make your second PR `local-cheetah => cheetah`: any potential conflict would have been resolve first locally during the rebase.

If you fond yourself resolving conflicts twice, don't forget to [use `rerere`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70922739/6309).

Comment: Do you mean local-cheetah on top of origin/cat after local-cat is merged into origin/cat?

Comment: Basically, rebase your local branch on top of the update remote *target* branch. If you do a PR from `cheetah` to `cat`, then yes, that would be `local-cheetah` on top of `origin/cat`.