# Git merge conflict issue, gir merge conflict while pulling

Tags: github

My coworker and I are working in the same branch which was cut from develop. There are many files to be taken care of by both of us.
The scenario I’m facing is that
I did some changes and pushed my code to the remote repo. My coworker also did some changes in his local and and now he is not able to take a pull. It shows merge conflict while pulling.

Can someone let me know how can we resolve this?
Based on my understanding, I think we made some changes in the same files and now to merge them, git is causing that conflict.

Comment: You need to manually merge the changes. If using the command line, `git pull` will present you with options. But of course it's easier with tools such as `tortoisegit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used tortoise git

> git tortoise > git diff

Then I manually resolved the git merge conflict by removing or modifying the code I didn’t want.
Then I committed the code and the issues were gone.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure to use:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

That way, a simple git pull will:

- stash your work in progress
- *rebase* your local commits (not yet pushed) on top of the updated remote upstream branch (instead of merging). That keep the history linear.

You can also [activate `rerere`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70922739/6309) in order to not resolve the same conflict over and over again.

Finally, in case of merge/rebase conflict, you will need to chose between "our" and "their" version in each file with conflict markers. As [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163659/6309), an IDE can help facilitate the visualization and resolution of such conflicts.