# `git svn rebase` vs `git rebase trunk`

Tags: git, svn, rebase

I'm working on a project that uses subversion for their repository. Because I need to make some changes that can't be sent to the svn server yet, I started using `git svn` so that I could do local checkins. My setup looks like this:

**Branches:** trunk (tracking svn trunk), master (pretty close to what's in svn), and topic.

```
*------------------ trunk
 \
  *-----------*--------- master
               \
                *-------- topic
```

**Workflow:**

```
[on branch master]
$ git svn fetch
$ git svn rebase
$ git checkout -b topic
$ git rebase master
[hack hack hack]
$ git commit -a
[once upstream is ready for my changes]
$ git svn fetch
$ git checkout master
$ git svn rebase
$ git checkout topic
$ git rebase master
$ git svn dcommit
$ git checkout master
$ git svn rebase
$ git branch -d topic
```

Presuming that no one commits to svn between `git svn fetch` and `git svn rebase`,
**Is `git svn rebase` run on master basically the same as `git rebase trunk` run on master?**

**Is there a more sensible workflow to use?** It seems like there's a lot of changing branches and rebasing going on. I understand that I want to be able to rebase my work on top of whatever's in svn, but it seems like I'm doing more rebases than are strictly necessary.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note, from [git svn](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-svn.html), as detailed in "[Why is the meaning of “ours” and “theirs” reversed with git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959443/why-is-the-meaning-of-ours-and-theirs-reversed-with-git-svn/2960751#2960751)":

```
git svn rebase
```

> This fetches revisions from the SVN parent of the current HEAD and rebases the current (uncommitted to SVN) work against it.

So you don't need the `git svn fetch` before your `git checkout master` and `git svn rebase`, especially if you track only `trunk` (parent of `master`).

---

Second point, the `git svn dcommit` would create revisions in SVN for each new commit on `master`, but your workflow doesn't show any new commit on `master`, only on `topic` (which isn't ever merged on `master`)

---

The [OP Sean McMillan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117587/sean-mcmillan) comments:

> According to the docs, `git svn dcommit` without a branch specified pushes the commits on the current HEAD, not just on `master`. So I commit to SVN from my branch, then rely on a `git svn rebase` on `master` to bring the commits back from SVN. I abandon the `topic` branch after I've `dcommited`. Is this not kosher?

He details that:

> I can't sent them to SVN... yet. Upstream wants to "freeze" the trunk for a release, meanwhile, I'm working on functionality for the next release.
>
> But the ultimate question is, "**is git rebase trunk master the same as git svn rebase on the master branch?**" If it is, then I don't need to be constantly changing my branches, just to rebase my master branch against SVN. But if it's not, and there's some kind of magic happening when I git svn rebase, I want to know.

To which I reply:

A `git svn fetch` followed by a `git rebase trunk master` would be the equivalent of a `git svn rebase`.

Comment: On the first: So I don't need to `git svn fetch` before I `git svn rebase`... As long as I'm on `master`. But if I'm on `topic`, `git svn fetch` will update `trunk`, but leave `master` and `topic` alone. I never `git svn rebase` my topic branch though, I  only `git rebase` it. Interesting to know.

Comment: @SeanMcMillan "As long as I'm on master": yes, that is the idea. And you do a `git checkout master` every time, so...

Comment: On the second: According to the docs, `git svn dcommit` without a branch specified pushes the commits on the current HEAD, not just on `master`. So I commit to SVN *from my branch*, then rely on a `git svn rebase` on `master` to bring the commits back from SVN. I abandon the `topic` branch after I've dcommited. Is this not kosher?

Comment: @SeanMcMillan I am not sure why you would `dcommit` while being on topic, since one premiss of your question is that you "need to make some changes that can't be sent to the svn server". That is why I questioned the use of `dcommit`.

Comment: But the ultimate question is, "is `git rebase trunk master` the same as `git svn rebase` on the master branch?" If it is, then I don't need to be constantly changing my branches, just to rebase my master branch against SVN. But if it's not, and there's some kind of magic happening when I `git svn rebase`, I want to know.

Comment: Ah.. I can't sent them to SVN... yet. Upstream wants to "freeze" the trunk for a release, meanwhile, I'm working on functionality for the *next* release.

Comment: "is git rebase trunk master the same as git svn rebase on the master branch?": no, the first is a pure git history rewrite of `master` on top of an unchanged `trunk` branch. The second will update `trunk` first.

Comment: I must not be communicating well today. Presuming that my `git svn fetch` has updated trunk, and that no one has committed to trunk since then, is the outcome the same? What primitive operations does `git svn` do when you `git svn rebase`?

Comment: @SeanMcMillan yes, sorry: a `git svn fetch` followed by a `git rebase trunk master` would be the equivalent of a `git svn rebase`.

Comment: That's what i suspected, but I wanted to confirm it. Please edit that into your answer. :-) Feel free to tweak the question to make it more clear too.

Comment: @SeanMcMillan answer edited, with the relevant part of the comments included, for more visibility.