# Git: Use git-merge-file to resolve conflicts using theirs/ours

Tags: git, git-svn, git-merge

I have don a `git svn rebase` and I got a conflict. I want to use `git-merge-file` to merge the two versions of the file by choosing the version on the server. `git-merge-file` has this option called `--theirs` but `git-merg-file` takes 3 parameters. How can I pass it just my file that contains the conflict markers and make it choose their version?

I also tried `git merge -Xtheirs file.cpp` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you can try:

```
git checkout --ours file.cpp
git add file.cpp
```

if you simply want to drop your local changes in favour of the upstream version.

Indeed, in the case of a rebase, --ours is the upstream, while --theirs are your local changes.

Comment: I did some tests using git-svn and I found out that --theirs gives me my version, and --ours gives me the version on the svn server. Do you have any idea why and if it's normal?

Comment: @JasonSwartz See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959443/why-is-the-meaning-of-ours-and-theirs-reversed-with-git-svn