# smartgit rebasing origin/local onto local / or in the opposite direction

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, smartgit, git-interactive-rebase

When I use **pull and rebase local change**  **or just fetch origin branch and then manually rebase local head via "`rebase HEAD To`"** to `origin/local` branch... I can get merging conflicts, but it's ok.

---

Only two things are disturbed me:

- first, the head after this not point to local branch, now he pointed to topmost commit of this branch, hence
- second rebasing process not starting (when it starts, we can see red color title "rebasing" after head name).

---

Can somebody to shed some light on this.
Also, I tried to perform the same operation on computer of my friend and everything is ok!
I want to have clear log's too. But still I don't resolve this problem I have using merging branch.

Comment: When you say "i am not dump", do you mean to say "I am not dumb"?

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of the (i) the main window and (ii) the Log window, showing relevant branches?

Comment: Sorry, i can't. Received message, that i needed minimum 10 reputations points to post images

Answer (score 0):

When using [SmartGit](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/), or any Git GUI tool, the operations are essentially abstracted versions of the Git commands you would run in the terminal. Rebasing can be a complex operation, especially when there are conflicts involved.

Rebasing is the process of moving or combining a sequence of commits to a new base commit.
When you **[`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)**, you are changing the base of your branch from one commit to another, making it appear as if you would create your branch from a different commit.
See "[Why is the meaning of “ours” and “theirs” reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2960751/6309) with `git rebase`"
Conflicts can occur during rebasing if the commits in the branch you are rebasing have changes in the same part of the code as the branch you are rebasing onto.

See [SmartGit rebase](https://docs.syntevo.com/SmartGit/Latest/Rebase.html)

Now, regarding the issues you mentioned:

1. **HEAD pointing to topmost commit**: That is expected behavior. When you rebase, your `HEAD` will point to the latest commit in the sequence of rebased commits. That is because the rebase operation essentially replays your commits on top of the branch you are rebasing onto. It makes it appear as if you had branched from the newer commit.
2. **Rebasing process not starting**: The red "rebasing" title you mention is the indication that a rebase operation is currently in progress. If you do not see it, it can mean:

   - The rebase finished successfully.
   - The rebase encountered conflicts and is waiting for you to resolve them.
   - There was an issue with the rebase operation.

See also "[Resolving conflicts in SmartGit - Finding conflicting files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38059620/6309)", or, for illustration, "[Using SmartGit to follow the GitFlow branching and workflow model](https://endjin.com/blog/2015/01/using-smartgit-to-follow-the-gitflow-branching-and-workflow-model)" by [Alice Waddicor](https://endjin.com/who-we-are/our-people/alice-waddicor/).