# Resolving conflicts in SmartGit - Finding conflicting files

Tags: git, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution, smartgit, git-merge-conflict

I have done a rebase in SmartGit. My respository is marked with a red **< rebasing >** in SmartGit

If I try to make any new commits I get the message:

*Rebase: You must edit all merge conflicts and then mark them as resolved using git add.*

This is what my working tree looks like:

[image]

I would like to resolve the merge conflicts but I am not familiar enough with git or SmartGit to know how to do this. I wish to invoke **Query|Conflict Solver** on the conflicted files but my problem is that I cannot find the conflicting files and the [documentation](https://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/How+to+resolve+conflicts) does not show how to do this. They refer to the "Directories"-pane which I cannot find, though it seems to be similar to the "Respositories"-pane. How do I find and resolve the conflicting files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The sceenshot shows the history of your repository. Use **Repository|Open Working Tree** to see the conflicts.

Comment: @mstrap Thanks. My problem as I stated is that I cannot find the conflicting files. Of course I have been in the Working Tree. I see files that are added and files that can be commited etc. but I do not know where to specifically look for the CONFLICTING files. How can I find them?

Comment: SmartGit will highlight conflicting files in the Files view (**Window|Files**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it appears we had similar problems: smartgit would tell me i need to resolve conflicts, but i could not find them anywhere. it was frustrating that this was not obvious, which ultimately led me to this post.

the solution was simple, my view settings were incorrect, and once fixed the conflicted file showed up within the main file setting. here you can see the [view settings for Files pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqJFr.png).

in the attached image, you will see a row of icons that determine which file is displayed. somehow, the folder icon (first one) was unchecked, which prevented it from displaying files within sub-folders, and therefore my conflicted file did not show.

the syntevo smartgit app does many things well, but it really muffed it when it came to clarifying the conflict-resolution process.

btw, thanks to @Arashsoft for his in-depth answer!

Answer (score 4):

If you check your Smartgit main window, you will see some of your files are like 
this:

[image: smartgit conflict]

You should double click on the conflicted files and the conflict resolver will open:

[image]

The next step is to merge two versions of the file (left and right windows) to one file (center window)

Comment: I guess this is the correct answer, but somehow these conflicts never showed up for me. I could therefore not resolve the problem and had to start version controlling from scratch. I will accept anyway. Do not know what the error depended on unfortunately.

Comment: Check filters at top-right side of files tab. Maybe the conflicted file is filtered.