# escape double quotes in git config from cmd

Tags: git, cmd

I want to create a batch file that initializes all the key/values in my `.gitconfig` file.

I have troubles trying to set the following section from cmd:

```
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    cmd = p4merge "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
```

I tried:

```
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd "p4merge \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\""
```

But the result is:

```
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    cmd = p4merge \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"
```

How should I escape that double quotes from cmd?

Comment: Did you try it from a cmd.exe or a git bash?

Comment: Im running it from cmd

Comment: Try the other option with the single quote, to see if this works better.

Comment: The option with the single quote doesn't work from windows cmd :(

Answer (score 6):

The answer to "[Git on Windows: How do you set up a mergetool?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/436040/6309)" proposes:

> - From a git bash session:

```
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd 'p4merge.exe \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"'
```

> - or, from a windows `cmd.exe` shell, using 3 double-quotes `"""` to escape one `"`:

```
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd "p4merge.exe """$BASE""" """$LOCAL""" """$REMOTE""" """$MERGED""""
```

So it depends if you launched `git-bash.bat` or [git-cmd.bat](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat)

Other examples in CMD:

```
git config --global core.editor """"C:\Users\vonc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe""" --wait"
# or
git config --global core.editor """"C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe""""
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thats what i tried from `cmd`, but im getting `cmd = p4merge.exe \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"` into `.gitconfig` file, literally (I mean, with the "\"). Is that ok?

Comment: @lante yes, the outer quotes are supposed to disappear once in the `.gitconfig`. The `\"` should work, but I would still test it first.

Comment: `$LOCAL` and `$REMOTE` should be in the reverse order: `\"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$MERGED\"`

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Interesting: do you have any link for that? I have always seens the BASE LOCAL REMOTE order myself when it comes to p4merge (https://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/git-for-window-tip-use-p4merge-as-mergetool/, https://gist.github.com/daredude/1350855, https://gist.github.com/robcthegeek/306395/cb22940c0651b1499a24281680d6de7f823b7422, https://gist.github.com/tony4d/3454372#gistcomment-1191983, etc...)

Comment: I simply tried that with `p4merge` 2012.1. Normally, REMOTE is blue and on the left, and LOCAL is green and on the right. Your way, they were swapped.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Was it during a rebase (where remote and local are reversed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2960751/6309)?

Comment: @VonC, exactly.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Oh, that would makes sense, then.

Comment: The backslash does not work in Windows cmd console. The command

`git config --global core.editor "\"C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe\""`

produces

`editor = \"C:/Program Files STANDALONE/Notepad++/notepad++.exe\"`

I ended up editing .gitconfig directly.

Comment: @AlexFainshtein 7 years later, I agree: I have edited the answer to fix the double-quotes escape in a CMD on Windows.

Comment: Good Lord - cmd.exe/Windows command line quoting and escaping is a mess.