# Git Config Double Quotes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, double-quotes, git-config

This was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534995/escape-double-quotes-in-git-config-from-cmd), but no solution was provided for PowerShell. The solution given does not work in PowerShell (specifically, PowerShell 5.1 within VSCode).

I have tried

```
git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd '"code --wait $MERGED"'
```

but I lose the double-quotes (i.e. there are no double-quotes in the corresponding `.gitconfig` file). FYI, the single-quotes are necessary to pass `$MERGED` as a string literal and not have PowerShell attempt to expand it.

I've also tried

```
echo '"code --wait $MERGED"' | git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd
```

```
git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd '`"code --wait $MERGED`"'
```

```
git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd @'
code --wait $MERGED
'@
```

but nothing works. Is there no way to do this from within PowerShell?

Additionally, I've researched [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745868/powershell-passing-json-string-to-curl), and the solution of

```
git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd '\"code --wait $MERGED\"'
```

nor

```
git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd "\"code --wait $MERGED\""
```

does not work either.

The closest I get is using

```
git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd '" code --wait $MERGED "'
```

but this outputs the spaces in the string as such:

```
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = " code --wait $MERGED "
```

Comment: If you wanna pass `$merged` as literal you'll need to escape the `$` too, so ```"`"code --wait `$MERGED`""```

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon That doesn't work either. The quotes are gone in the `.gitignore` file still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, an **obscure workaround is required** (see the bottom section for a generic solution via an installable module):

```
git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd --% "\"code --wait $MERGED\""
```

**Note**: This assumes that you want to end up with the following in `~/.gitconfig`, which probably *isn't* your intent:

```
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = \"code --wait $MERGED\"
```

Instead, as [one of the answers you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534995/escape-double-quotes-in-git-config-from-cmd) suggests, **only the `$MERGED` part should be double-quoted** with *embedded* double quotes, in which case you should use (see the alternative at the bottom):

```
git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd --% "code --wait \"$MERGED\""
```

That would give you:

```
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait \"$MERGED\"
```

**That is, only those *individual arguments* in the *shell command* that your value constitutes that need double-quoting *for the shell's sake* must be enclosed in `"..."`.**

Note that it is `git` that re-escapes verbatim `"` chars. in the given configuration value as `\"` in the config file. *Unescaped* `"` in the config file - which have *syntactic* function *for `git` itself* - are only used if you pass a value with leading and/or trailing spaces, so as to delimit the value as a whole; **values with (interior) spaces do *not* themselves require manual double-quoting: `git` stores them as-is in the config file, except for escaping embedded `\` as `\\` and `"` as `\"`**.

Passing `--% "code --wait \"$MERGED\""` from PowerShell signals the intent to pass *verbatim*  value `code --wait "$MERGED"` to `git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd`, which is the proper formulation of a *`sh` command line*<sup>[1]</sup> (`sh` is a POSIX-compatible shell that `git` uses even on Windows, via a `bash` implementation that ships with it) in which the `"..."` around (environment) variable reference `$MERGED` ensure that the expanded value is passed as-is to the target binary, `code`, even if it contains spaces, for instance.

You can verify this by *querying* the value afterwards:

```
# After running the command above:
PS> git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd
code --wait "$MERGED"
```

`git config` and the configuration file format are documented [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), also available locally by running `git help config` or, alternatively, on Unix-like platforms only, `man git-config`

---

**Explanation of the workaround:**

Use of `--%`, the [stop-parsing symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing), allows you to control the exact quoting of the subsequent arguments passed to external programs (while also suppressing expansion of PowerShell variables, so that `$MERGED` is left as-is), whereas PowerShell by default performs *re-quoting* behind the scenes, after having performed its own parsing.

Leaving aside that double-quoting the entire command line is ultimately *not* the right approach, **purely from a PowerShell syntax perspective what you tried, `'"code --wait $MERGED"'`, *should* work** - PowerShell should automatically translate that to `"\"code --wait $MERGED\""` behind the scenes - **but as of PowerShell 7.1 doesn't, due to a long-standing bug**, described in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).

While explicit `\`-escaping of embedded `"` chars.(!) is *typically* a better workaround and works reliably in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, there are edge cases in *Windows PowerShell* where it doesn't, and you've hit one of them:

```sh
# Alternative workaround for *PowerShell (Core) v7+ only*
git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd '\"code --wait $MERGED\"'
```

The reason this doesn't work in Windows PowerShell is that it mistakenly concludes that the `\"...\"` constitutes *syntactic* double-quoting and therefore doesn't enclose the argument in `"..."`; that is, instead of passing `"\"...\""`, it passes just `\"...\"` as part of the target process' command line.

Note that quoting arguments *individually* avoids the edge case discussed, so that explicit `\`-escaping works even in Windows PowerShell:

```sh
# Also works in Windows PowerShell, because the edge case is avoided.
git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd 'code --wait \"$MERGED\"'
```

---

**Generic solution via module `Native`**:

If you want to solve quoting problems for *most*<sup>[2]</sup> (on Windows) / *all* (on Unix) calls to external programs, consider my [`Native` module](https://github.com/mklement0/Native)'s `ie` function, which encapsulates all required workarounds:

```
# Install the module in the current user's scope.
Install-Module Native

# Simply prepend `ie` to your external-program calls, which correctly
# handles all behind-the-scenes re-quoting, allowing you to focus on 
# PowerShell syntax only.
ie git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd 'code --wait "$MERGED"'
```

---

<sup>[1] `git` appears to be invoking `sh` as follows (using `sh` syntax with placeholders for illustration):

`sh -c '<config-value> "$@"' '<config-value>' <git-supplied args>`

That is, the command line stored in the configuration value is invoked with `git`-supplied pass-through arguments appended. Note that the first first post `-c` argument is again the configuration value, which binds to `$0`, i.e. sets the invocation name, and is therefore *not* part of the array of pass-through arguments, `"$@"`. An example of a `git`-supplied pass-through argument is the path of a file to edit that is passed to the command line stored in the `core.editor` configuration value.</sup>

<sup>[2] A solution that works with *all* external programs is fundamentally impossible on Windows, because each program can decide for itself how it parses the string that encodes the arguments being passed. However, there are a few widespread patterns that `ie` is aware of and applies appropriately, which notably makes it work robustly with batch files and `msiexec`-like executables.</sup>

Comment: Apologies for the delay; I was tied up with other business. Thank you! This is great! I have accepted your answer. Excellent work! Much appreciated!

Comment: No worries; thanks for accepting; my pleasure. I'm glad we got to a shared understanding (and I learned a thing or two).

Answer (score 0):

This works in PowerShell 7.4.1 within VSCode:

```
git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd "`"code --wait $MERGED`""
```