# Git bash can't type anything

Tags: git

[image: mingw64-git]

Text:

```sh
MINGW64/c/hen/USER/desktop/boden34-repo-Inst

USER DESKTOP-PKARPV3 NINGUS4 (master)

$ cd desktop/troders34-repo-test

USER DESKTOP-PKARPV3 NING-/desktop/troders34-repo-test (master)

index.html

USER DESKTOP-PKARPV3 MINGW54 /desktop/troders34-repo-test (master)

$ git commit
```

What should I do next?

In this case, I typed "`git commit`" in my Git bash session, then nothing happened.
Just entered to next blank line. I couldn't type anything and show nothing.

When I wanted to close the git bash, it appeared a warning "Processes are running in session:"

Comment: Presumably your editor has opened and is waiting for you to type a commit message. If you didn't want that, you could include the commit message in your original command, e.g. `git commit -m 'this is the message'`.

Comment: Please don't post the problem as an image. Especially in this case it's easy enough to copy the text.

Comment: thank you @matt i didn't specify the command so git was stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Type first to check the value of [`core.editor`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreeditor):

```
git config core.editor
```

See which editor is set, and change it to one which will respond.

For instance, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25535431/6309), from a CMD session:

```
git config --global core.editor """"C:\Users\vonc\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe""" --wait -n"
# or
git config --global core.editor """"C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe""""
```