# How and why does "git checkout HEAD" result in different results for "--theirs" and "--ours"?

Tags: git, vim, github, git-rebase, git-checkout

When I am in the middle of a `rebase` conflict, I'd like to see the changes that would be instituted by `--ours` , `--theirs` and `HEAD`.

So, I check out all of them (literally):

`git checkout --ours <new_file>`

`vim <new_file>`

...I examine the file...

`git checkout --theirs <new_file>`

`vim <new_file>`

...I examine the file...

`git checkout HEAD <new_file>`

`vim <new_file>`

...I examine the file...

Then, I go back and checkout `theirs` and `ours`:

`git checkout --theirs <new-file>`

`vim <new-file>`

For some reason, `--theirs` and `--ours` have both conformed to the version when I checked out `HEAD`. I understand the `git checkout` is supposed to change the working directory and the index, but even when I checkout `--theirs` **again** it is still like the `HEAD` version.

How/why is this?  And is there a way to get back my original `--theirs` and `--ours` versions?  Thanks.

Comment: found a similar question with a detailed [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2959443/3711562) , it could help

Answer (score 2):

Git uses the `--ours` and `--theirs` arguments to `git checkout` to select which "side" of a conflicted merge to extract.  More precisely, when you have a conflicted merge, there are, for each conflicted ("unmerged") path, three<sup>1</sup> entries in git's index/staging-area for that path.  Git numbers these:

`:1:path`    the merge-base version of the file
       `:2:path`    the "ours" version of the file
       `:3:path`    the "theirs" version of the file

Note that `:0:path` is "missing", here: slot zero is reserved for the resolved (merged) path.

When you did `git checkout HEAD path`, git thought you were resolving the conflict.  It ditched the other three versions and filled in slot 0.  In fact, if you replace `HEAD` with any branch or "tree-ish" specifier (e.g. `git checkout branch1 path`), it will also think you are resolving the conflict.

Fortunately, there's a way to tell git to (re)create the merge conflict, re-populating the other three slots (and ditching the version in slot 0):

`$ git checkout -m path`

Git's merge attempt winds up in your work directory as usual.

One slight drawback is that the notations after the `<<<<` etc are lost (you can actually supply them, as they come out of special git environment variables, but it's rarely worth bothering, I think).  [Edit to add note: I'm referring to the extra information added *after* the markers, e.g.:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:more information here
```

It's the "more information here" that I have seen vanish.]

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, *up to* three entries: the obvious entries are left out if the file is deleted in some of the commits being merged.

Comment: You say `It ditched the other three versions and filled in slot 0.`  Does it fill in slot 0 with whatever I most recently checked out?

Comment: Also, what is a `path` in this context?  I assume you mean a path to a conflicted file?  Or is this a `git` term?

Comment: Last comment, I promise:  IF it clears out the other "paths" 1, 2 and 3, then why is it that I'm still able to use `git checkout --theirs <new-file>`?  It seems to me that, rather than ditching them, it just fills in 1, 2, and 3 with the same contents of those in slot 0?

Comment: Yes, slot 0 gets the "resolved" version of the file (and slots 1-3 get cleared out).  I italicized "path" to indicate that you can fill in any file path here, e.g., `:1:dir/sub/file.txt`.  It seems like `git checkout` should complain that there is no `--ours` or `--theirs` version, at this point—using `:2:file.txt` gets an error, when there's no slot-2 entry—but perhaps the idea here is that you can apply it without error to a large collection of files (e.g., a directory) to resolve only the conflicted files in that directory.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between `merge-base version` in `:1:` and `ours` in `:2:`?  They seem the same on my machine?

Comment: It's possible that the merge-base version #1 and version #2 could be the same, but in general, for that case you would not get a conflict.  (The files might differ slightly in white-space, which can result in conflicts that git can see, but people can't.)

Comment: But, in a rebase conflict, it would seem to me that they would always be the same, right?  Because the branch you are rebasing onto would always be `--ours` which would be the same as the `merge-base` version.

Comment: No, though it's hard to describe properly in a comment.  Suppose you're rebasing commits `C-D`, which branch off from common point `o`, onto the tip of main-line development which goes `o-A-B`.  Rebase copies commit `C` by diffing `C` vs `o` and then trying to apply that to `B` to make `C'`.  If there's a conflict here, `--ours` is `B` and `--theirs` is `C` (due to rebase's viewpoint swap) while the base version is still `o`.  Likewise when copying `D`, "ours" is now `C'`, "theirs" is `D`, base remains `o`.  Makes more sense with graph drawn, but I can't do that in a comment.