# How to git rebase and use ours as strategy using VSCode without using the terminal

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How to git rebase and use ours as strategy using VSCode without using the terminal. I tried everything but couldn't find it with or without using extensions.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned, [in case of conflict, accepting the changes in HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59657521/6309) would be using a "ours" strategy.

But if there is no conflict, and you *need* to keep the ours strategy by default, then you need a [merge driver in place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31560423/6309), declared in a `.gitattributes`.

Once this configuration is done, any rebase would use the equivalent of a ours strategy, and no terminal would be needed.
You would need to change the .gitattributes afterward though, of that "ours" strategy would be permanent.

Comment: But how can you do this automatically for all conflicting commits in vscode

Comment: That would be where the merge driver, declared in the gitattributes file, would help.